# how to use sliding menu with multiple activity?

Tags: android, menu, sliding

I want to create an android app with multiple activity and i want to make it's menu with sliding menu which every menu refers to each activity.

How do I do it?

Comment: sliding menu? Did you mean swipe on the screen to get next activity?

Comment: no, i mean side menu likes facebook app.

Comment: can you post an example screenshot here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my favorite SlidingMenu Library : https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu